# Locking the computer disables speech recognition on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, microsoft-speech-api, microsoft-speech-platform, system.speech.recognition

I work with `SpeechRecognitionEngine` from the namespace `System.Speech` in inproc-mode for doing some automation work. The speech recognition is started via `RecognizeAsync`.

It works fine, however, when the computer gets locked, speech recognition stops. As soon as the computer gets unlocked, the recognition is active again. 
While  this is probably a meaningful behavior for most applications, for mine, it is an issue. I have searched the web, but not found a solution to disable this behaviour.

How can I parameterize the SpeechRecognition not to stop when the computer is locked?

*(Please note: The app is a conventional Windows WPF application, not a Windows Store App)*

Comment: Why the close-request? It’s perfectly about coding. Is it because the word “configure”? Should I have better written “parameterize”? I’m not native english speaking and therefore please forgive me the wrongly used word. But I think, this question makes perfectly sense for SO. Changed the word.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas which might be too crazy to work to hopefully trigger some ideas that might work:

- Using ControlChannelTrigger to keep pinging your app to wake up and try recognizing speech at intervals?  This listener allows your app to process network data in the background.
- Try out Google Chrome's hotword (*OK, Google*) extension and see if it works behind the lock screen.  If they can do it, then it's possible.
- Do you have to lock the screen, isn't it possible to not have it locked?

Some references:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263238.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977056.aspx

Similar questions:

- http://gotspeech.net/forums/thread/11826.aspx
- http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ab82528-0d1c-492e-9c15-38730d88b3e9/speechrecognitionengine-pauses-on-lockscreen?forum=Offtopic

Comment: The app does not sleep, it does other tasks without problems (under the lock screen), it's only the speech recognition which stops to work. By the way, it's a conventional windows app, not a windows store app). But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have *"Enable voice activation"* option enabled in Windows?

It looks like the behavior you describe is expected when *"Enable voice activation"* option is disabled in **Control Panel | Speech recognition**. Though, it can be unrelated to locked Windows.

See ["Setting speech options"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Setting-speech-options):

> **Enable voice activation**
>   Sets Speech Recognition to start in sleep mode and allows Speech Recognition to enter sleep mode when you
>   say "stop listening."

On the other hand, I don't think that using Speech Recognition with locked device is valid operation (security reasons). Unless you are going to spell your password instead of typing it. :)

Comment: Sadly, this does not solve the Problem. But thank you for your post.